# How do I perform string splitting in a form before submission?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a form which requires the input data to be validated before submission. The types of validation checks - which can be more than 1 per input element - are entered into the input element, and the validation performed is by jQuery.

My approach is to put all the types of validation that are required and separated by commas - such as "blank,email" - into the "checks" attribute of the input element. The jQuery will then extract this part, split it into an array, and loop through each validation type.

The problem is, I do not want to submit the form until all the validation checks are completed. But when I use the "split" function, as it returns an array, the program takes it as a boolean true was returned and the form is submitted after the first input element.

Here's a sample of the form, taking note that it looks similar with all other fields:

```html
<tr>
  <td>Full Name</td>
  <td><input type="TEXT" name="AccountName" check="blank"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>NRIC</td>
  <td><input type="TEXT" name="AccountNRIC" check="blank,nric" maxlength="9"></td>
</tr>
```

And here's the jQuery validation code:

```js
// PERFORM VALIDATION CHECKS
$("form").submit(function()
                 {
  // LOOP THROUGH ALL INPUT FIELDS
  $("form input, form textarea, form select").each(function()
                                                   {
    // IF NONE OF THE INPUT'S PARENTS ARE HIDDEN
    if($(this).parents(":hidden").length == 0)
    {
      var thisValue = $(this).val();
      var checkWhat = $(this).attr("check");
      var checkArray = checkWhat.split(",");
      for(var i=0; i<checkArray.length; i++)
      {
        switch(checkArray[i])
        {
          case "blank": alert(CheckBlank(thisValue)); break;
          case "nric": alert(ValidateNRIC(thisValue)); break;
          case "email": alert(ValidateEmail(thisValue)); break;
        }
      }
    }
  });
});
```

I should clarify that an error checking variable hasn't been added in yet as the codes are still being tested in parts.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: why not use e.preventDefault if there's an error on validation?

     .submit(function(e){ 
          //    validation
          if has error then e.preventDefault();
      })

Comment: As far as I know `check` is not a valid attribute. Use a data-attribute instead, e.g. `data-check`.

Comment: Hi Vincent, thank you for your response. I have no idea how can I go about using it to my advantage. Can you advise me on that? Any code snippets or links would be useful.

Comment: maybe he treated it as custom attribute and accepted by jQuery

Comment: Hi Bram, thank you for your response. Yes it's not a valid tag in HTML, but I believe jQuery can pick up custom attributes by using the .attr() function.

Comment: You can believe anything you want, it won't make it valid HTML and you can make it valid HTML by using a data-attribute which is also readable by jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

```
// PERFORM VALIDATION CHECKS
$("form").submit(function()
                 {
  // LOOP THROUGH ALL INPUT FIELDS
  $("form input, form textarea, form select").each(function(e)
                                                   {
    // IF NONE OF THE INPUT'S PARENTS ARE HIDDEN
    if($(this).parents(":hidden").length == 0)
    {
      var _hasError = false;
      var thisValue = $(this).val();
      var checkWhat = $(this).attr("check");
      var checkArray = checkWhat.split(",");
      for(var i=0; i<checkArray.length; i++)
      {
        switch(checkArray[i])
        {
          case "blank": if (!CheckBlank(thisValue)) { _hasError = true; } ; break;
          case "nric": if (!ValidateNRIC(thisValue)) { _hasError = true; }; break;
          case "email": if (!ValidateEmail(thisValue)) { _hasError = true; }; break;
        }
      }

      if (_hasError) e.preventDefault();
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your help! I'll try it out tomorrow and see if it works. Though I should clarify that I haven't added in an error checking variable as I was testing my code in parts. Thank you once again =)

Comment: no problem. _hasError is just a flag. preventDefault() is a function that stops the default behavior of the event. Happy Coding!

Answer (score 1):

You can stop the form submit default action, do what ever logic you want, then submit.

```
// PERFORM VALIDATION CHECKS
$("form").submit(function( event ){
    event.preventDefault(); // stops submit action

    // do your form validation here.

});
```

There also is no check HTML attribute. You could use it but it is not standard. Or you could just grab the input value. Most people add data- to custom HTML attributes ( data-check ).